# SQLite3 поиск первого слова в столбце

Tags: sqlite3, like

Собственно: в столбце `col_1` нужно найти совпадения по первому слову, до первого же пробела:

```
WHERE col_1 LIKE '%s '
```

**Термин** один

**Термин** два

**Термин** три

или

**Объект** один

**Объект** два

**Объект** три

Возможно ли при помощи LIKE это реализовать и если возможно, то каким образом?

Comment: Если Вам нужно найти все записи начинающиеся на `Термин`  то  `WHERE col_1 LIKE 'Термин% '`

Comment: @ФеоктистПупырышкин, нет, мне нужно найти все первые одинаковые слова в столбце

Comment: Надо разбить строку по пробелам, взять первую часть и потом по ней сделать `group by`. Конкретнее не скажу, не знаю есть ли в `sqlite` функция разбиения по пробелу.

Comment: @CrazyElf, вот я тоже не знаю :)

Comment: Посмотрите вот здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24258878/how-to-split-comma-separated-values там разбиение строки по запятой, но думаю можно и под ваши нужды заточить

Comment: @ФеоктистПупырышкин, вот такое составил, но что-то никак, а проверить что именно получается в результате запроса, даже не знаю как. Вот оно: `sprintf(sql, "SELECT *, SUBSTR('taxon', 0, instr('taxon',' ')) FROM numbers WHERE taxon = '%s'", taxon);`.

Входное (в столбце) там примерно такое «Tillandsia purpurea Ruiz et Pav.», пользовательский ввод «Tillandsia», т. е., как раз первое слово до первого пробела. Но, не находит. Видать, что-то не так режет в строке.

Comment: К сожалению у меня `sqlite3` чтобы проверить в чем у Вас ошибка. Направление вам задали, дальше придется самому :)

Comment: @Max, ну так вы задали полное соответствие `taxon = '%s'` вот он и не находит. Вы не задали имя для подстроки, чтобы отбор по ней проводить.

Comment: @needKVAS, ну так вот пользовательский ввод: `printf("Enter genus and press enter: \n"); 
fgets(taxon, sizeof(taxon), stdin);`. Как же по-иному то запрашивать?

Comment: Вы меня не поняли. Вы находите подстроку, но фильтруете всё равно по всему полю. Должно быть как в ответе что-то типа `SELECT *, SUBSTRING(taxon, 1, INSTR(taxon, ' ') - 1) as short
FROM numbers WHERE short = '%s'`. Но я не понимаю почему вас не устроило самое простое `SELECT * FROM numbers WHERE taxon like '%s %%'`.

Comment: @needKVAS, ну где же вы раньше то были))) И не надо городить всех этих правил громоздких. Всё гениально просто. Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Ну, я погуглил насчёт отрезания по пробелу. Можно что-то такое сделать:

```sql
SELECT SUBSTRING(col_1, 1, INSTR(col_1, ' ') - 1) as first,
       count(1) as count
GROUP BY first
HAVING count(1) > 1
```

Так мы найдём повторяющиеся термины и посчитаем число повторений. Дальше если вам нужно все записи с этими терминами вывести, то можно использовать этот запрос в качестве подзапроса.